# Objective C closing pragma mark

Tags: objective-c, pragma

I use #pragma mark extensively in my projects and I was wondering if there is a closing pragma mark statement.  I couldn't seem to find one.

Comment: what to you want to close? maybe, some compiler directives or something else? could you be more specific, please?

Answer (score 3):

`#pragma mark` does not have a scope, it is like a `//` comment so there is no end.

It wold seem that another `#pragma mark name` or `#pragma mark -` is a fitting end.

Comment: I was thinking of #pragma mark as a block comment like you would use in CSS with a start and an end.   The more I think about it you really don't need an end.  Just organize your code so that all the sections are separated.

Answer (score 2):

No I don't believe there is, however I don't see the issue as when one "section" has finished another one will begin, so simply use a `#pragma mark - Next Section` to mark it.

Comment: In addition, you could use `#pragma mark -` as a 'closing' one.

Comment: @Jeff the only problem with that is that it starts a section with no title.